# How to use the application.hbs in an ember pod app?

Tags: ember.js

In the regular file structure, ember uses app/templates/application.hbs as the base template.

How can I use a base template in the ember pod style?

Comment: Nothing different. Same as default.

Comment: in pod-style the application-template would live here: `app/pods/application/template.hbs`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be at `app/application/template.hbs`